# Using findAll within a certain tag in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get all text in a certain column in a certain part of an XML file. To this end, I'm using BeautifulSoup.

When I use BeautifulSoup's `FindAll` function, it returns the columns from the certain part like it should, *plus* all the matching columns after that part, so after the closing tag.

To illustrate, an example:

My file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doc>
    <row>
        <entry colname="col2" align="left"><p>stuff</p></entry>
    </row>
    <body>
        <row><!--[1]-->
            <entry colname="col1" align="right"><p><id="1"/>1</p></entry>
            <entry colname="col2" align="left"><p>I want this part</p></entry>
        </row>
        <row><!--[2]-->
            <entry colname="col1" align="right"><p><id="2"/>2</p></entry>
            <entry colname="col2" align="left"><p>I want this part2</p></entry>
        </row>
        <row>
            <othertag>moreStuff</othertag>
        </row>
    </body>
    <row>
        <entry colname="col2" align="left"><p>I <b>don't</b> want this part</p></entry>
    </row>
</doc>
```

My script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
soup = bs(open('test.xml', encoding='utf-8').read(), 'xml')
soup.body.findAll('entry', {'colname': 'col2'})
```

Edited script with identical output:

```
soup = bs(open('test.xml', encoding='utf-8').read(), 'xml')
part = soup.find('body')
part.findAll('entry', {'colname': 'col2'})
```

The output:

```
[<entry align="left" colname="col2"><p>I want this part</p></entry>,
 <entry align="left" colname="col2"><p>I want this part2</p></entry>,
 <entry align="left" colname="col2"><p>I <b>don't</b> want this part</p></entry>]
```

Where the last entry shouldn't be there. How to fix this?

(Due to varying number of correct and incorrect entries throughout my files just ditching the last element of the array isn't an option)

Comment: Find `body` first, then do your `findAll` on it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching for `body`, then using `findAll` on it should give you what you want.
But you said that it don't ... So I tested out and cannot reproduce your problem.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
xml = '''
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doc>
    <row>
        <entry colname="col2" align="left"><p>stuff</p></entry>
    </row>
    <body>
        <row><!--[1]-->
            <entry colname="col1" align="right"><p><id="1"/>1</p></entry>
            <entry colname="col2" align="left"><p>I want this part</p></entry>
        </row>
        <row><!--[2]-->
            <entry colname="col1" align="right"><p><id="2"/>2</p></entry>
            <entry colname="col2" align="left"><p>I want this part2</p></entry>
        </row>
        <row>
            <othertag>moreStuff</othertag>
        </row>
    </body>
    <row>
        <entry colname="col2" align="left"><p>I <b>don't</b> want this part</p></entry>
    </row>
</doc>
'''

soup = bs(xml, 'html.parser')

print(soup.findAll('entry', {'colname': 'col2'}))

part = soup.find('body')
print(part.findAll('entry', {'colname': 'col2'}))
```

Which gives me the expected output:

```
$ python /tmp/zbefberg.py
[<entry align="left" colname="col2"><p>stuff</p></entry>, <entry align="left" colname="col2"><p>I want this part</p></entry>, <entry align="left" colname="col2"><p>I want this part2</p></entry>, <entry align="left" colname="col2"><p>I <b>don't</b> want this part</p></entry>]
[<entry align="left" colname="col2"><p>I want this part</p></entry>, <entry align="left" colname="col2"><p>I want this part2</p></entry>]
```

From there, try out my small example, if the problem persist try reinstalling `BF4`, then reinstall `lxml`, if it persist try using the `'html.parser'` parser.

Answer (score 1):

Using "xml" option to create the soup somehow results in all `<row>` after opening tag of `body` goes inside the `<body>` element. Print `soup.prettify()` to see how BS parses your XML. That said, using "html.parser" instead of "xml", as also mentioned in the other answer, fixed the problem

```
>>> print soup.prettify()
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doc>
 <row>
  <entry align="left" colname="col2">
   <p>
    stuff
   </p>
  </entry>
 </row>
 <body>
  <row>
   <!--[1]-->
   <entry align="right" colname="col1">
    <p>
     <id>
      ="1"/&gt;1
     </id>
    </p>
    <entry align="left" colname="col2">
     <p>
      I want this part
     </p>
    </entry>
   </entry>
   <row>
    <!--[2]-->
    <entry align="right" colname="col1">
     <p>
      <id>
       ="2"/&gt;2
      </id>
     </p>
     <entry align="left" colname="col2">
      <p>
       I want this part2
      </p>
     </entry>
    </entry>
    <row>
     <othertag>
      moreStuff
     </othertag>
    </row>
   </row>
   <row>
    <entry align="left" colname="col2">
     <p>
      I
      <b>
       don't
      </b>
      want this part
     </p>
    </entry>
   </row>
  </row>
 </body>
</doc>
```